# Tool to know what is making the desktop load longer than usual

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there such a tool?

My desktop as of late is taking longer to load than usual. I'd say it takes more than 20 seconds from GDM login until I see the desktop. Aside from disabling all app-indicators and testing it manually one by one, what else should be done? The only indicator I remember activating lately was bluetooth and I have already  disabled it from Startup Applications. No improvement.

I know of bootchart, but I don't really have a problem with boot. It is only after I login that the issue occurs. I'm on Natty Narwhal.

*Updating this thread.... The issue seems to have fixed itself and I did not even do anything. It is really weird. I guess this is how Gnome works (and talk about not recognizing your theme and reverting to Windows 95-like look. How about that?). I have been a long time KDE user and I never encountered issues like this one. The KDE then may have booted into the desktop longer (from KDM) but at least I know it was consistent.

Comment: This thread on Ubuntu forums looks very close to the problem I am having: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1766139. It's not resolved. Just this last login (from cold boot), I timed the loading close to a minute before desktop shows.

Answer (score 2):

*(The problem was solved by the OP)*

> The issue seems to have fixed itself and I did not even do anything. It is really weird. I guess this is how Gnome works (and talk about not recognizing your theme and reverting to Windows 95-like look. How about that?). I have been a long time KDE user and I never encountered issues like this one. The KDE then may have booted into the desktop longer (from KDM) but at least I know it was consistent.

Comment: Just so you know, press 'esc' on the ubuntu splash screen (with the loading dots) to see the log and see what's going on.

Comment: Ummm the boot up duration was not the issue here. (I'm  referring of `boot` as the time from POWER ON to GDM for clarity).  It took the normal time to boot on my machine. The problem is when I login to my account it took like half a minute or even more for the desktop to load, i.e. See the Launcher/Unity visible. Otherwise it's like half a minute++ of wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the booting process in command line style. Edit /etc/default/grub

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Un-comment the line:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Now the update the grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your system. Next boot it will show all process loading during boot. So you can easily determine which program takes long time to load.

Comment: Again, the boot up process was not the issue. It was loading from GDM login to Unity desktop that's causing the delay. But it got fixed without me doing anything.